# How to save seekbar value in android studio?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, sharedpreferences

I have a media player with a seek bar inside of a bottom sheet, and whenever I play whatever sound on the URL that I'm having the seek bar goes just fine but when I close the bottom sheet and open it up again the seek bar reach to 100% of its value and the sounds are still on the beginning.

How do I make the seek bar work when the sound is playing in the background?

Please help me, and thanks in advance.

**My fragment**

```
    private var mediaPlayer:MediaPlayer? = null
 private var oTime = 0
private var sTime: Int = 0
private var eTime: Int = 0

  fun quranMp3(){

 quranPlay?.setOnClickListener {
        // الفاتحة

        if (quranPageNum?.equals(0)!!){

            if (mediaPlayer == null){
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, Uri.parse("https://server7.mp3quran.net/basit/Almusshaf-Al-Mojawwad/001.mp3"))
                Log.d("quranMp3", "ID: ${mediaPlayer!!.audioSessionId}")

                val position = mediaPlayer!!.currentPosition/100
                mp3SeekBar.progress = position
                //totalTime = mediaPlayer!!.duration

                eTime = mediaPlayer!!.duration.toLong().toInt()
                sTime = mediaPlayer!!.currentPosition.toLong().toInt()

                if (oTime == 0) {
                    quranSeekBar!!.setMax(eTime)
                    oTime = 1
                }

                playerDuration?.text = String.format(
                    "%d min, %d sec", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(eTime.toLong()),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(eTime.toLong()) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(eTime.toLong())))

                playerPosition?.text = String.format(
                    "%d min, %d sec", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(sTime.toLong()),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(sTime.toLong()) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(sTime.toLong())))





                initializeSeekBar()



            }

            mediaPlayer?.start()
            Log.d("QuranMp3", "Duration: ${mediaPlayer!!.duration/1000} seconds")

        }

   quranPause?.setOnClickListener {

        if (mediaPlayer !== null){
            mediaPlayer?.pause()
            Log.d("QuranMp3", "Paused at: ${mediaPlayer!!.duration/1000} seconds")

        }



 mp3SeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener( object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener{

            override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar?, progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {


                if (fromUser){
                    mediaPlayer?.seekTo(progress)

                }
            }
            override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {
                val Toast = Toast.makeText(context,"تتبع..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                Toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 50, 50)
                Toast.show()
            }
            override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar) {
                val Toast = Toast.makeText(context,"يرجى الانتظار للحصول على البيانات..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                Toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 50 ,50)
                Toast.show()


            }

        })

 private fun initializeSeekBar() {

    val mp3SeekBar = view?.findViewById<SeekBar>(R.id.mp3SeekBar)
    mp3SeekBar?.max = mediaPlayer!!.duration
    val playerPosition = view?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.player_position)
    val playerDuration =  view?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.player_duraation)

    val seekbar = this.activity?.getSharedPreferences("QuranPdf", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)


    val handler = Handler()
    handler.postDelayed(object : Runnable {

        override fun run() {


            try {

                sTime = mediaPlayer!!.currentPosition

                playerDuration!!.text = String.format(
                    "%d min, %d sec", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(eTime.toLong()),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(eTime.toLong()) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(eTime.toLong())))

                playerPosition?.text = String.format(
                    "%d min, %d sec", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(sTime.toLong()),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(sTime.toLong()) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(sTime.toLong())))


                mp3SeekBar?.progress = sTime //mediaPlayer!!.currentPosition
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000)

            } catch (e: Exception) {
                mp3SeekBar?.progress = 0

            }
        }

    }, 0)
}
```

**My App Photos**

as you can when I open the bottom sheet and press play, everything works fine.

*first one*

[image]!

but when I close the bottom sheet and open it up again the sound is working but the seek bar and the texts are not working.

*second one*
[image]

Java and Kotlin are acceptable

Comment: Is the above code part of your bottom sheet?

Comment: @March3April4  no this code is for the is for mediaplayer and the seek bar in the bottom sheet fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this problem. Apparently, I have to initialize the seekbar in

onResume method.

this is the solution to my question. I only need to  add this code

```
 override fun onResume() {


    try {

        if (mediaPlayer !=null && mediaPlayer!!.isPlaying){
            initializeSeekBar()
        }

    }catch (e : Exception){
        e.printStackTrace()
    }

    super.onResume()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are wrapping the `seekbar` updation logic inside `mediaplayer == null` condition which will be `false` once the `MediaPlayer` is initialised.

```
quranPlay?.setOnClickListener {
        // الفاتحة
      if (quranPageNum?.equals(0)!!){
            if (mediaPlayer == null){
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, Uri.parse("https://server7.mp3quran.net/basit/Almusshaf-Al-Mojawwad/001.mp3"))
             }//end it here, rest the code should be outside if condition
       //seek bar logic and rest of the code
       }
  }
```

Comment: I did it and still, the seek bar gives the same issue when I close the bottom sheet and open it up again

Comment: do you have any idea why?